# Resetting Password for SQL Server Authentication Login for Cherwell Application

Tags: sql-server

I had reset the password for a Cherwell Application login on SQL Server, and applied that password on the application server that runs Cherwell.

Cherwell seems to work, however SQL Logs are still reporting login failures even though Cherwell is accessible. The problem with this is:

1. It is filling up the SQL Logs extremely fast because the login failures happen about every 4 seconds
2. I need to enable "Enforce password policy" and "Enforce password expiration" on the Cherwell login in SQL. The login failures will inherently lock out the user.

What am I missing here? Are there multiple locations where that password must be applied on the application end (configuration files, etc)? Is there a service/services that must be stopped or restarted to prevent the constant pinging into the databases server and locking out the user login?

The specific SQL error code is ID 18456, Serverity: 14, State: 8 Which is simply that the "password did not match that for the login provided".

Comment: It should have IP addresses in the SQL error log. Which should give you information where you still have the old password.